# What happened to the K-Tron in the command center?

Tags: robots, valerian-and-city-thousand-planets, valerian-and-laureline

Towards the end of *Valerian and the City of a Thousand Planets* we see Commander Arün Filitt's K-Tron robots split into two groups.  One group is with the soldiers deep down in the space station, while the other group is standing just outside the command center.

> At the crucial moment, based on orders from Commander Filitt, both groups of K-Tron start shooting up the humans.  At both locations the soldiers seem incapable of defending themselves from the K-Tron.
>   It is only deep in the station at the Pearl's lair that the K-Tron are destroyed - by Valérian.  Only his pistol has the fire power to destroy the K-Tron (which raises other questions - how come Valérian's pistol conveniently packs such a punch, and how come he shoots so well?)
> But there doesn't seem to be an equivalent of Valérian at the command center, yet at some point in time the shooting by K-Tron stops.

So what happed to the group of K-Tron at the command center?

Comment: His pistol packs a bigger punch because the AI on his ship (Alex) has remotely armed him with some very serious and probably illegal ordnance to use. His aim is spectacular because he's literally the best of the best of the best (with honours).

Comment: @Valorum I know Valérian commanded Alex to do something just before the fire fight and that it was to do with his weapon, but it was so quick that I didn't get a full grasp of what was intended.

Comment: *"“Alex?” said Valerian, shouting to be heard over the sound of bullets, “if you can hear me, load me up with all you’ve got!”
A green light flashed on Valerian’s gun.
“Acknowledged, Major,” came Alex’s welcome voice. “Here goes… fifty infras, twenty anti-flux, twelve ultra-heatseekers.”*". As far as I can tell he sent the bullets from the ship **through exospace** into the gun's clip.

Comment: @Valorum is that a quote from the movie or the novelization?  Because if it's the movie I totally missed that.

Comment: It's from the novelisation. In the film he just says "*Alex, load me up with all you’ve got!”* just before he jumps through the barrier and starts shooting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During the firefight all but two of the K-Trons in the Command Centre were destroyed.

[image]

We cut away for a few seconds and when the scene resumes, all of the robots have been destroyed.

If we turn to the film's [Official Novelisation](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/33216612-valerian-and-the-city-of-a-thousand-planets), we can see the missing part of the scene.

> The general directed his impotent grief and outrage upon the final two
>   robots, turning on them with sudden fury — firing and firing without
>   stopping. The last one toppled and fell.

Comment: Which raises the question as to why a general in the command center has access to weapons that can destroy a K-Tron, when the weapons employed by front line combat troops seemed so ineffective.

Comment: @PeterM - They aren't ineffective. The soldiers destroyed four of the six robots with their rifles and damaged the others. The General destroyed the other two with his sidearm while their attention was focused on the man repairing the console.

Comment: My recollection of the movie  (from seeing it this week) is that Valérian destroyed way more than just 2 K-Tron.  There was a longish montage of him jumping and sliding and popping up all over the place as he dispatched them.  While I may have missed soldiers dispatching K-Tron, Valerian seemed to do the majority of the work.

Comment: @PeterM - Yes. The K-Tron attacked in two groups; 6 for the command centre and about twelve(?) for the Pearl ship. The soldiers (and general) in the command centre destroyed all six of theirs. The soldiers at the Pearl ship destroyed two (that we know of), Valerian destroyed ten and two were knocked over when the ship went into Exospace.

Comment: I think you are making part of my point for me!  The command center soldiers destroyed 6 K-Tron, but a large number of front line combat troops only managed to destroy 2.   But yeah I had mis-red your comment above discussing who destroyed what in the command center.

Comment: The troops at the barrier were mostly ambushed from behind. They didn't have time to respond with well-aimed shots unlike the troops in the command centre who were executing a classic small-room defence behind pillars and consoles.